# Creating javascript array (multidimentional) or javascript object is a better approach

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, multidimensional-array

Below is the json structure :

```
jsonResponse
    Folder 01
        Product 01 - Folder 01
        Product 02 - Folder 01
        Product 03 - Folder 01
    Folder 02
        Product 01 - Folder 02
        Product 02 - Folder 02
        Product 03 - Folder 02
    Folder 03
        Product 01 - Folder 03
        Product 02 - Folder 03
        Product 03 - Folder 03
    Folder 04
        Product 01 - Folder 04
        Product 02 - Folder 04
        Product 03 - Folder 04
```

And my requirement is to store folder name and product in respective folders. I am able to store folder name in an array but need to store products in respective folder, which i am not able to accomplish. I am using jquery1.8 to read json response and then by using each function i am creating the folder array.

Help with this highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question? How to create the structure in the first place? Where does the source data come from? What does your code using `each` look like?

Comment: Below is the json structure :.... this is not JSON

Comment: Guffa's suggested data-structure (below) looks good to me. If you control the source of the JSON (please show your JSON - what you've shown is just text) you can start with it in that format rather than reading it in and looping through it with `.each()`.

Comment: sorry friend that i didn't pasted proper json structure, will make sure next time that i will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would make an array of folder object, where each object contains an array of product objects. That gives flexibility to hold any additional data that you would reasonably need to send along about the folders and products, for example the price of a product.

Example of the structure:

```
var folders = [
  {
    name: 'Folder 01',
    products [
      { name : 'Product 01' },
      { name : 'Product 02' },
      { name : 'Product 03' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Folder 02',
    products [
      { name : 'Product 01' },
      { name : 'Product 02' }
    ]
  }
];
```

Example of building an array from data:

```
var folders = [];

// data that you would get from looping the JSON data:
var folderName = 'Folder 01'
var products = ['Product 01', 'Product 02'];

var prod = [];
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  prod.push({ name: products[i] });
}
var folder = { name: folderName, products: prod };
folders.push(folder);
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, but how could i store all other products. Folder names are dynamic, i mean i don't have any control on it. We are creating a 'Whatchlist' in which user can store product name in Default folder or custom folder which user can create.

Comment: @PrashantShetty: Loop through the parsed JSON data, then you get the name for each folder, and then loop through the products for that folder. I can't provide any exact code for looping through the JSON, as I don't know what it looks like.